# MySql querying taking too long

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-performance, database-optimization

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    i1 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i2 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i3 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i4 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i5 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i6 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i7 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i8 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    i9 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o1 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o2 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o3 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o4 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o5 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o6 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o7 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o8 DECIMAL(10, 5),
    o9 DECIMAL(10, 5)
); 
CREATE INDEX input_data_index
ON temp (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9);
CREATE INDEX test_index
ON temp (o1);
```

I am trying to search through this table using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM temp t
INNER JOIN temp x
ON t.i1 = x.i1 
AND t.i2 = x.i2
AND t.i3 = x.i3
AND t.i4 = x.i4
AND t.i5 = x.i5
AND t.i6 = x.i6
AND t.i7 = x.i7
AND t.i8 = x.i8
AND t.i9 = x.i9
WHERE t.o1 != x.o1;
```

The table contains 180,362 rows. If I take out the where clause it only takes 0.157 seconds to run however with the where clause it takes a really long time to run (in excess of 300 seconds) at which point I just cancel it.

Why does it take so long to run when that where clause is added? 
Do you have any suggestions on how I can speed this up?

EDIT:

When I run the explain statement using the original index I had I get: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWUZ7.jpg)

When I run the explain statement using the one suggest by @Simulant (adding o1 to the index) I get: [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn5xg.jpg)

but it still takes a really long time for this query to execute as well.

Comment: It may be running the where query for each row individually on the join, ie it is executing thousands of querys.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of appalling poor design

Comment: Try removing the index on `o1`.  It might be confusing the optimizer.

Comment: @Strawberry any suggestions on how to fix the design?

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns (above 2, say), you can be sure that your design is flawed. I don't know what i's and o's are so I can't really comment further, but see normalization.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: About how many rows in the result with `WHERE`?  Without `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values of o1, where the i values are the same, you might consider:

```
select i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9,
       group_concat(o1)
from temp
group by i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9;
```

This is not exactly the same result set, but it might satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but no it doesn't produce the desired result. Also I don't know who down voted your post, lol

Comment: If you hover over the down arrow, it may offer a clue.

Comment: @User9813 . . . If the only reason is that it produces singletons, then you can include `having min(o1) <> max(o1)`.

Comment: @User9813 - In what way does it not produce the desired results?  Are you saying that it fails to have 40 columns, with the `i` columns duplicated?  Or that you need all 20 `o` columns?  Or something else?

Comment: @RickJames I mean that I want to the just the original table (with no duplicate columns), which I realize now that you can't see since I used "*" in my original select statement. Also I just want to see the rows containing where i1, i2 ... i9 are the same for both tables but o1 is different for both tables.

Comment: @User9813 - what do you want to display??  Perhaps `SELECT i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, x.o1, t.o1` ??

Comment: I want to see `SELECT t.i1, t.i2, t.i3, t.i4, t.i5, t.i6, t.i7, t.i8, t.i9, t.o1`, and for each row for (t.i1, t.i2, t.i3, t.i4, t.i5, t.i6, t.i7, t.i8, t.i9) they should contain the same values but t.o1 should be different for each row

Comment: @User9813 . . . Then just use `select distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

The Columns `i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9` are indexed in the same index, so your query without the `where` is fully utilized by the index. your column `o1` is indexed in another index. But a query can only use one index at the time for one table. What you should do is add all your columns needed for the query to the same index.

```
CREATE INDEX input_data_index
ON temp (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, o1);
```

Using the [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) statement can help you to find out how good your index reduces the scanned rows.

Comment: Based on this line of reasoning, change `WHERE` to `HAVING` would help.

Answer (score 0):

Have

```
INDEX((i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9,  o1)
```

And change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE t.o1 > x.o1;
```

This will cut in half the number of rows output, and *might* change the way the query is executed.